# PyCharm Support for PyQt6 on M1

Tags: python, user-interface, pycharm, apple-m1, pyqt6

I've now swapped over to Pycharm and PyQt5 as it had better support an integration.

Our school has just upgraded to M1 chips and now my solution doesn't work.

I can download the latest version of python 3.10.2.

I then run the following command in terminal.

```
Python3.10.2 -m pip install PyQt6
```

To test the code I then type this into idle:

```
import sys

from PyQt6 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
widget.resize(400, 200)

widget.setWindowTitle("This is PyQt Widget example")

widget.show()

exit(app.exec())
```

This all works perfectly and a window will be displayed.

I then open up Pycharm 2021.3 community edition.

Select the same interpreter and load global dependencies.

I run it and then this is the error I get

[image: Error in Pycharm]

From what I can read PyQt6 supports both the Arm and 86 architecture from the same download source. Is it possible to force an interpreter to use just the arm or does PyCharm know to do this intuitively?

I'm trying to get students to use the drop and drag builder with QT designer first.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to use proper [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (ensure that you're properly using [all options](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) and check the post preview), and avoid posting code or debug output as images, but use text instead (using the code formatting options suggested above).

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same python? With the command you point out it seems that you are using the system python, instead pycharm uses a virtualenv.

Comment: @eyllanesc I think so. When creating the project I selected the drop and chose the python 3.10 interpreter. I thought that it copied across all of the contents. It also copied across the PyQT6 libraries.

Comment: Don't be silly, installing a package is not just copying but there are many other tasks. Use pycharm to install that package and don't copy files.

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry just to clarify, do you mean to use the pip command to install PyQt6 inside of the PyCharm terminal?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#packages-tool-window